videojs icons in stencil web component
I'm trying to build a video player web component based on stenciljs and I would like to use videojs but I see some issues on icons.
I made this example to show you the problem https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/videojs-with-stenciljs-ryvq8c
Do you guys have some idea on how to solve it?

ok, I found that I have to disable shadow dom to make it works!
